# Extend line bundle on regular curve to it's regular model

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, neron-models

Let $S$ be the spectrum of an excellent discrete valuation ring with field of fractions $K$ and $C$ be a proper integral regular curve over $K$.

Assume, $C$ admits a proper regular flat model $\mathscr{C} \to S$. Let $\mathcal{L}_{\eta}$ a line bundle on $C$.

**Q:** Is there any general reason why $\mathcal{L}_{\eta}$ should always be always extendable to a line bundle $\mathcal{L}$ over the model $\mathscr{C} $ based crucialy on it's assumed regularity?

Source: It seems that this principle was used in [arXiv:2110.00545](https://arxiv.org/abs/2110.00545)  in the proof of Theorem 4.3 (p 41/42)

Comment: Extend to any coherent sheaf and then take reflexivization (double dual). A reflexive sheaf on a two-dimensional regular scheme is locally free, so you obtain a line bundle this way.

Comment: @PiotrAchinger: is there a 'deeper' reason why this holds for surfaces, but presumably  not higher dimensional regular schemes? More precisely, does there exist for an integral regular scheme $X$ an "iff-criterion" when a reflexive coherent sheaf is locally free? And iff yes, can the assumption "regular" be somehow weakended?

Comment: Why don't we just take the associated divisor $D$ of $\mathcal{L}_{\eta}$ on $C$ and the closure of this divisor on $\mathcal{C}$? This is a Weil divisor and by regularity it is Cartier. So we get a line bundle on $\mathcal{C}$.

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar: yes, that looks to be extendable to even  more general situations beyond dimension two setting - namely when we dealing with proper flat fibrations $X \to S$ with regular $X$ and $S$ Dedekind. Then one can under relative mind conditions show that the closure in $X$ of a Weil divisor of generic fiber is flat over $S$ and conseqeuntly is a Weil divisor in $X$ and apply again this Cartier- Weil identification

Comment: As Ariyan says you can take the closure of a divisor, which works as long as the model is locally factorial. For surfaces you get more: you can extend vector bundles, not only line bundles.

Comment: @PiotrAchinger: yes Ariyan Javanpeykar's argument working with Weil divisors I understand so far. The question is "how far" goes the argumentation via the techniques using the reflexive sheaf? Say we have a reflexive sheaf on an integral scheme $X$. As you said the if $X$ 2-dim + regular (... even loc factorial suffice), then it is locally free. Now how far can the assumptions on $X$ be "maximally" weakened (regarding dimension and regularity) in order to have still this implication that "reflexive" implies "locally free"?